# The 'fas' that I use in my class changes the font-family of the text

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome

The fas by default changes the font-family of my text. Can someone help me out with the issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="fontawesome-pro-6.0.0-alpha3/fontawesome6/pro/css/all.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="New folder/Icons/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="box">
<div class="scores fas fa-star">Font-family Changed</div>
<div class="scores bi-star-fill">Font-family Applied</div>
</div>
<style>
body{
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your approach to import the css from is wrong.

you need a `i` tag to do.

```html
<i class="scores fas fa-star">Font-family Changed</div>
<i class="scores bi-star-fill">Font-family Applied</div>
```

I think this would be an better way to do.

If you need some explains, watch this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nHKjsqw0zw8